# add textbox dynamicaly using dropdown with jQuery

Tags: jquery, dynamic, drop-down-menu

[Dynamically add textbox using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204122/dynamically-add-textbox-using-jquery)
from the link above i want something like that, but i want to use dropdown menu.
here is my code
http://jsfiddle.net/boyee007/VyG6F/
the textbox will be added depends on the value.
if you select 3 will **only show 3 textboxes**, and if 2 will **only show 2 textboxes** and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$("#ppl").change(function(){

    // The easiest way is of course to delete all textboxes before adding new ones
    //$("#holder").html("");

    var count = $("#holder input").length;
    var requested = parseInt($("#ppl").val(),10);

    if (requested > count) {
        for(i=count; i<requested; i++) {
        var $ctrl = $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'text', name:'text', value:'text'});        
            $("#holder").append($ctrl);
        }
    }
    else if (requested < count) {
        var x = requested - 1;
        $("#holder input:gt(" + x + ")").remove();
    }
});
```

See it running [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rajeevRF/vdbjpLy4/1/).

Comment: thanks :). works great. but i dont want it continuesly add the textbox when i select another value. if you `select 5 will it only shows 5 textboxes`, then if you `select 3 (it only show 3 textboxes)`, NOT add another 3 textboxes. i hope that make sense :)

Comment: See my edited answer. Although it will be easier to delete everything and start from scratch, the user will lose any text she had already entered. For this reason on update I add/remove required elements to reach the correct count.

Answer (score 0):

here is your solution...check it out....

[**Solution**](http://jsfiddle.net/LfLFa/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.